# Click it up by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any ways to click up the div function by javascript like `$('#divAB7').clicked` to accomplish the following functionality same done when clicked on Read more link:

```
<a href="#divAB7" class="btn1 fl">Read More</a>`
```

---

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function js() {
    $(".myHref").on("click", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#divAB7').trigger('click');
    });
}
</script>

<body>
    <a href='#' class="myHref">Read More</a>
    <input type='submit' onClick='js()'>
    <div id='divAB7' style="display:none;">
       hello
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(".myHref").on("click", function (e)
 {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#divAB7').trigger('click');
  });

  </script>

<body>
<a href='#' class="myHref">Read More</a>

<div id='divAB7' style="display:none;" onclick="alert('div is Clicked')">
hello
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You cannot remove the href attribute alltogether. Use `href="#"` for links that have no actual href.

Comment: @FelixKling this triggers the div's click with the ID. when pressing the href  - it triggers the Divs click.

Comment: Yes, but now every `myHref` link will trigger a click on the same div. `$(this.href).click()` seems to be a better approach (imo).

Comment: thanx but the code didn't work :( kindly see the edited code above how i tested it may be i did something wrong so kindly indicate if there is

Comment: @Faizan: On click, you execute `js` which itself *binds an event handler*. That is not the idea. You should bind the event handler once the DOM was loaded. I suggest you read about some jQuery basics: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery Also, as long as you don't bind any click event handler to `#divAB7`, you will see no effect, since clicking on a `div` normally doesn't do anything. Here is an example in which direction it *could* go: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx3uv/ But it more looks like instead of triggering a click event on the div, you want to *show* it.

Comment: @FelixKling dont be such a petty , it was an example of 1 to 1 - what he should do - in general. and according to his html - he is using just one and i dont see another Anchor. so my answer does work for HIS html. Does your answers to every question is in GENERAL MODE ? i dont think so.

Comment: @royi kindly see my code above i made it  to perform the functionality of showing div that didn't work kindly see did i do something wrong with it cause i used your piece of code in it....

Comment: @FelixKling the code you mentioned in jsfiddle is working like you bind the click function of div that is performing what is inside that function only what i am trying to do is show the hidden div functionality as we click on link <a href="#divAB7" class="btn1 fl">Read More</a>` and it performs accordingly but that click functionality of href="#divAB7" should be done by js function...